# What are the dimensions of the inflation slow-roll parameters?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

The inflation slow-roll parameters are:

$\epsilon = \frac{M_{pl}^2}{2}(\frac{V'}{V})^2$
$\eta=M_{pl}^2 \frac{V''}{V}$

What are the dimensions of $\epsilon$ and $\eta$? What about $V$ and its derivatives? $M_{pl}$ clearly has dimensions of mass.

The slow-roll conditions are usually given as $\epsilon \ll 1$ and $\eta \ll 1$, which suggests that they are dimensionless, but in that case I am not sure what the dimensions of $V$ and its derivatives are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parameters are indeed dimensionless. Dimension of $V$ (which in units $c=\hbar=1$ has the dimension of $\text{mass}^4$, the dimension of energy density) is irrelevant since it enters both in numerator and denominator. So, the dimension of $\frac{V'}{V}$ is simply the inverse dimension of the scalar field $\phi$, (since $V'\equiv\frac{d V(\phi)}{d\phi}$) which has the dimension of mass.

Note, that both quantities could also be expressed as a purely geometric dimensionless quantities relating to the evolution of Hubble parameter $H$:
$$ 
\epsilon = - \frac{\dot H}{H^2} = - \frac{d\ln H}{dN},
$$
$$
\eta =\epsilon - \frac{1}{2 \epsilon} \frac{d \epsilon}{dN}  ,
$$
where $dN=H dt$  is dimensionless, with $N$ measuring the number of $e$-foldings of exponential expansion.

Reference:

- Baumann, Daniel. *TASI lectures on inflation.* (2009), [arXiv:0907.5424](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5424).

Comment: Do you know of any reference that explicitly treats the dimension of $V$, preferably in SI units? If it's in Daniel Bauman's lecture notes, I can't find it. I can't find it in other resources I've looked at either.

Comment: For that matter, why is $m^4$ the dimension of energy density? Energy density should intuitively have dimensions $J/m^3$. $J$ is related to mass by $E = mc^2$, but that still leaves the length cubed in the denominator.

Comment: @Allure: *For that matter, why is $m^4$ the dimension of energy density?* Energy density should have dimension $\text{Energy}/\text{volume}$ in units $\hbar=c=1$ energy has dimension $m^1$ and volume $m^{-3}$.This is *not GR units* (which have $G=c=1$), but HEP units! Here length has dimension of inverse mass (as a check you could use SI definition of Compton length $\ell=\hbar/(mc)$).

Comment: *If it's in Daniel Bauman's lecture notes, I can't find it* Baumann's Appendix D2 is a reference to expressing $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ as a *geometric quantities* independent of specific unit system used for field equation.